# Meaning of "当鬼"

Tags: meaning

I really like this music

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j2311FZWoFQ

And not long before the beginning it says 
"每个人都想当鬼"

The subtitle says it means "Everyone wants to give orders." But I don't think "当鬼" means "to give orders." Can anyone help?

Comment: I don't see it in the video

Comment: Tang Ho. That's because I put the wrong link. This is the right one:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HqmpIQ9l-uA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably referring to this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HqmpIQ9l-uA

In the Chinese version of hide-and-seek, the person that looks for other players is called a 鬼 (literally "ghost"), and 当鬼 means "to become this player (that catches others)".

In the lyrics, it's probably a metaphoric expression that refers to a powerful position, thus "giving orders"

some example sentences (当鬼 is usually used exclusively in the hide-and-seek game context, unless used metaphorically):

下回你当鬼 (you be the catcher next round)
我喜欢当鬼，因为当鬼好玩 (I like being the catcher because being the catcher is fun)

Comment: That's right. I published the wrong video 'cause I posted a playlist's video so it redirect to the wrong one haha. But your answer is exactly what I was looking for. I didn't understand what "当鬼" could mean. "Represent ghost" used to pop-up in my mind and yet didn't make sense. Haha. Thank you.

Comment: Does this aply to the "tag" game? You know. The one on which everyone runs and there's 1 person who chases the others.

Comment: Not sure if the tag game is a thing in China (haven't played it myself in China as a kid). If it is, it would make sense to call the player who chases others a 鬼 since it's similar to the hide and seek situation

Answer (score 0):

at 1:27, they are making ghost money in a kitchen,  鬼 is also joker in cards, the biggest card.

The song is laughing at our society, everybody want to be number one, want to use products to attract spotlight.

You can find these images: chess, office workers in suites, crying to get toys obviously satires giant baby.

Comment: Thank your for the answer. But an interpretation of the song is not exactly what I was looking for. I wanted to know what this mean even 'cause I only knew "鬼" means "ghost". Now I know it means the "catcher" at the seek 'n hide game and also "Joker" as you stated. Thank you! ("the catcher" fills perfectly in this context)